# How to handle cookies in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

What is the best way to handle cookies in Codename One (and make sure it works for iOS and Android, and future versions)

I saw that there are setCookiesEnabled() and setUseNativeCookieStore() methods in ConnectionRequest, and also people say we should override cookieReceived(Cookie c) method.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding `cookieReceived` is probably the only thing you need to do for most typical cookie handling. You will get a parsed `Cookie` object that you can work with within that method and can implement your handling logic.

Comment: I put in connectionRequest.setCookiesEnabled(true); and         ConnectionRequest.setUseNativeCookieStore(true) ... and it is working perfectly. (So, I guess there is no need to override cookieReceived() and the hassle having to manage how/where to store the cookie data.)